# Create 3D space with colour values

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, 3d

For this semester, we HAVE to work in Visual Studio, at least partly.

My group and I are working with tracking hand movement in 3D space, and I have a horrible 3D array set up that can hold values. Now, my question is: Does Visual Studio have a method of setting up a (rotatable) 3D space that can also display, for example, greyscale colour values where each individual voxel can have an assigned value?

I'm not adept at MSVS, but from what I can tell, NET and/or XNA can render 3D objects - I just don't see a way of creating or editing them.

Will I have to give creating a Matlab script a try, and if so, how can I move my values from VS to Matlab?

If this question is too vague or broad, please provide me with some good Google search terms - I've run out of ideas.

Comment: You can use [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/features-3d-graphics/) to do that. Since you tagged OpenCV, it provides a (very simple) 3D visualizer based on vtk: [viz](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/viz/doc/viz.html). You can pass values around (if needed) with csv, yml, or binary files.

Comment: @Miki thanks. I tagged openCV since we are using the Ceemple plugin for VS. I can't tell if vtk can be used with VS, if it's a plugin or what it is?

Comment: VS is just an IDE. You can use any library you want, like VTK, in your code.